# Prestashop : remove shopping cart from homepage only (transformer theme)

Tags: shopping-cart, prestashop, transformer-model

I'm working on a transformer theme and I would like to remove the shopping cart from the home page only (without a display:none if possible)
I tried editing the module "Right bar cart block" but to no effect (even deactivating it doesn't change anything)
Do you have any idea of how to do this ?
I had a look in the index.tpl index.php and the header.tpl but couldn't find any include shopping cart in the code.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Find the module at BackOffice > Modules > Positions, click the "edit" icon and on that page add "index.php" at Exceptions.